# Distribution of the rank of a sample from a normal distribution among a set of samples from a different normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, ranking

I draw a single sample from a given standard normal distribution: $Y \sim N(0, 1)$. I also draw $n$ samples from a different normal distribution: $X_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for $i=1...n$. What is the probability distribution of the rank of $Y$ among all $(n + 1)$ samples? i.e. what are the probabilities that: $Y$ is larger than any of $\\{X_i\\}$, larger than all but one of $\\{X_i\\}$, larger than all but two of $\\{X_i\\}$, ... smaller than all of $\\{X_i\\}$?

Note this is not a homework exercise, I'm at work and it's a step in a real-world application!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Correcting my daft initial answer - thank you to @whuber!]

I'm assuming that $Y$ and the $X_i$ are all independent of each other.

Conditional on $Y=y$, the probability that any one of the $X_i$ is less than $Y$ is
$$
P(X_i < Y|Y=y) =  P(X_i < y)= \Phi\left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)
$$
where $\Phi(.)$ is the CDF of the standard Normal.

Now let $U$ be the rank of $Y$, so $U=0$ if $Y$ is less than all of the $X_i$, $U=1$ if $Y$ is less than exactly one of them, etc. Notice that we have $(U | Y=y) \sim \mathrm{Bin}\left(n,\Phi\left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)  \right)$.

Putting everything together, we have
$$
\begin{align}
P(U=k) & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(U=k|Y=y) f_Y(y) dy \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  {n \choose k} \Phi\left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^k \left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \right)^{n-k} \, \phi(y) dy
\end{align}
$$
where $\phi(.)$ is the PDF of the standard Normal.

Comment: +1 Conditioning on $Y$ looks like a good approach and might be the simplest way to solve this problem.

Comment: Many thanks to Doctor Milt for providing the answer. Also to whuber for pointing out the issue with his previous answer, and jbowman for checking it using simulation in the deleted post below. It's more complicated than I'd hoped but I'm convinced it's correct and I doubt it can be simplified. I'll just have to ensure I code it efficiently for my application....